# CALL_PHONE vs CALL_PHONE_PRIVLEGED

Tags: android

What is difference between permissions CALL_PHONE  and  CALL_PHONE_PRIVLEGED. After reading there definitions it appears they do more or less the same things.

CALL_PHONE: Allows an application to initiate a phone call without going through the Dialer user interface for the user to confirm the call being placed.

CALL_PRIVILEGED: Allows an application to call any phone number, including emergency numbers, without going through the Dialer user interface for the user to confirm the call being placed.

Can someone please explain the minute difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> any phone number, including emergency numbers

"Can dial 911" (or other emergency numbers, as valid in the specific location - e.g. 112 in EU)

You probably don't want just any ol' app calling the police of its own accord.